# using index value of previous widget

Tags: flutter, dart

```
children: [
        Container(
          // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.white, blurRadius: 1, offset: Offset(0, 0)),
              ]),
        ),
        CarouselSlider.builder(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            viewportFraction: 1,
          ),
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, idx, realIndex) {
            return buildImage(articles, urlImages[idx], idx, context);
            
          },
        ),
        DotsIndicator(
          dotsCount: 10,
          position: idx.toDouble(),
          decorator: DotsDecorator(
            size: const Size.square(6.0),
            activeSize: const Size(22.0, 6.0),
            activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
            activeColor: Colors.blue,
            spacing: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
          ),
        ),
      ],
```

The problem here is DotIndicator cannot see the current idx value therefore cannot see the current position of the widget.

How can I fix that

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create another `currentIdx` as a global variable (of the current widget) and use it like something below:

```dart
 itemBuilder: (context, idx, realIndex) {
            currentIdx = idx;
            return buildImage(articles, urlImages[idx], idx, context);
            
          },
```

Then you can replace `idx.toDouble()` in `DotIndicator` by `currentIdx.toDouble()`. And you need to make sure that the widget rebuilds correctly to make the code works.

Comment: I am getting this error if I add `currentIdx.toDouble()`

The non-nullable local variable 'currentIdx' must be assigned before it can be used.
Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path.

Comment: Have you declared `currentIdx` as a global variable? Ex: declare `int currentIdx = 0` above the `build` method.